# Unable to connect via USB since upgrading to iOS 6

Tags: iphone

I cannot connect my iPhone to my automobile's USB port after recently upgrading to iOS 6. I first noticed this in a rental car (and assumed the rental car's USB was malfunctioning). After returning home it no longer worked in my vehicles. BTW, the ports will no longer charge the iPhone, either.

Then when I returned to work and connected the iPhone to my Windows 7 PC, Windows 7 no longer recognizes the iPhone.

This problem eliminates a large part of how I use the iPhone as a tool. What could the problem be? Should I revert back to iOS 5?

Comment: I could see how the car might have become a problem, my iphone cannot use some thirdparty chargers and accessories after the iOS5 upgrade, but Windows 7 _should not_ have a problem connecting to the phone! I assume you have tried another USB cable and made sure is it an original Apple cable?

Comment: Have you updated to iOS 6.0.1?  That fixed the problems that I had with my iPhone 4S and the USB port on my car stereo.  However, I never had any problems with charging.  Are you using the same USB cable on all these devices?  Maybe it's faulty.